Finding the number of zeros of a function
Suppose we have a function that asymptotically behaves as a polynomial. For example, something like $$f(x) = \sum^N_{n=0} a_n x^n + \sum_{m=1}^M\frac{b_m}{x^m}.$$
Then, of course, for large $x$ this can be approximated by just the first part $\sum^N_{n=0} a_n x^n$ and we can determine the number of zeros of this function.
Will we be able to make a statement about the number of zeros of $f$ in its entirety?

It depends on what secrets you're hiding by "asymptotically behaves as a polynomial". Perhaps in the nicest case you might have that $f$ is holomorphic. Then Rouche's theorem would tell you that the zeros are very strongly controlled. But if instead you draw a squiggly line around the origin and then connect it to a polynomial in a non-holomorphic way, then clearly you can say nothing --- despite the fact that any such squiggle function is also asymptotically a polynomial.

I should've specified, but I consider $a_n$ and $b_m$ all to be real, so I'm afraid no complex analysis here :(

We can rewrite $f$ as $$f(x) = \sum^N_{n=0} a_n x^n + \sum_{m=1}^M\frac{b_m}{x^m}=\dfrac{a_0x^M+a_1x^{M+1}+\cdots+a_Nx^{N+M}+b_1x^{M-1}+\cdots+b_M}{x^M}$$
Thus, the zeroes of $f$ will be the same as those of $$g(x)=a_0x^M+a_1x^{M+1}+\cdots+a_Nx^{N+M}+b_1x^{M-1}+\cdots+b_M$$
But $g$ is a polynomial of degree $N+M$, so $f$ will have at most $N+M$ roots.

this is indeed what I was finding too. So unless $a_n$ and $b_m$ are specified in more detail, we can't make any more specific statements about the roots.

@Geigercounter That's what it seems indeed.  We could possibly find a radius $r$ in terms of $a_n,b_m$ such that all of the roots (if they exist) are in the ball of that radius, but probably not much more.
